# Deny URLs with a parent .. in the path in apache

Tags: security, httpd, httpd.conf

I was wondering if there was a simple way to make apache httpd deny (403) any URLs which contain a parent `..` in the path.

So far I have tried (ignoring the flase positives for simplicity)

```
<LocationMatch "\.\.">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</LocationMatch>
```

But that didn't work. The directory has `Allow from all` in it. Am I on the right track or is there an easier way to do this (like there was in Fasttrack back in the 90s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it by using [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/):

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "../" "log,deny,msg:'Directory Traversal Attack Detected'"
```

Testing with some requests:

```
http://domain.com/../../../../etc/passwd
```

and examine the audit log, you'll see something like this:

`[modsecurity] [client x.x.x.x] [domain domain.com] [302] [/20120816/20120816-1529/20120816-152911-1np2Nn8AAAEAA
Aq6EU0AAAAG]  [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf"] [line "305"] [msg "Directory Traversal Attack 
Detected"] Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "../" at REQUEST_URI.`

Comment: I agree with the answer but would suggest that the pattern should be `"\.\./"`.